# How to specify output directory with "mini-css-extract-plugin"?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I am using the `mini-css-extract-plugin` to extract the CSS from a bundle to a file. I need to drop that file in a different place in the filesystem.

How do I configure the `mini-css-extract-plugin` to drop the CSS file to a different path than the JS bundle?

Comment: You can't do that. You can only specify the folder relative to the output folder specified on your webpack config. You would need to manually/automate the copy after the build is success

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let's assume the following config:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist") // this is the default value
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css" // change this RELATIVE to your output.path!
    })
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Where your output path would resolve to - as an example - `/home/terribledev/projects/some-project/dist`.

If you change the filename property of the `MiniCssExtractPlugin` options object to `../../[name].css`, it will now be output to `/home/terribledev/projects/yourcssfile.css`, e.g.:

```js
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "../../[name].css"
    })
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Comment: What if you want to customize the filename? Is there a way to have the output filename match the initial css filename (and not the js filename that holds the import statement)?

Comment: how to save in a `css/` directory in `dist` directory?

Comment: @Sisir see my answer

Answer (score 8):

To specify an output path within the build directory, I include the subdirectory in the filename:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // ...
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'), // should be an absolute path
      filename: 'js/[name].js', // relative to output.path
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].css", // relative to output.path
        }),
    ],
    // ...
}
```

I've tested this in Webpack versions 4 and 5 with success. Check out the docs for [Webpack output](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename) to learn more.